# What's good practice when banning an account?

Tags: session, language-agnostic

Let's say a user is banned in a website, but his session is still active. What's the best way of preventing him from performing an action that a banned user is *not* allowed to do?

The two plausible solutions I came up with are

- making an additional checking previous to every "major" action,
  like making a post in the forum, sending a private message, etc. to make sure
  he is not banned (checking with the database)
- destroying his session

Now, the latter solution could be done by setting an expiration for the cookie, but this would be bothersome for the rest of the users as they would have to log in again.

Other option would be setting a timeout in the session in which the scripts checks if he's banned with the database and then destroying his session if he is, but this seems like a bit too much.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean by setting an expiration for the setting cookie, I would recommend against it. You want the control to be on the server side - don't trust your clients; they can easily prevent a cookie on their side from being destroyed.

Hopefully, whatever framework you're using has a way to delete the server-side data associated with a user's session, instead, invalidating the client's session id.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is object oriented, you could do a check in your constructor, if the user is banned, and if he is, unset his session/call the log out function.